# Why the binding does not work?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn

```
public class Game {
    public Player Player1 {
        get { return gameSettings.Player1; }
    }
}

public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public int TotalScores {
        get { return moves.Sum(move => move.ComposableWord.Length); }
    }       

    public void AddMove(Move move) {
        if (move == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("move", "Move can not be null.");

        moves.Add(move);

        OnPropertyChanged("TotalScores");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In the view

```
 <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=Game.Player1}">                    
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalScores}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

The DataContext of the View is set to GameBoardPageViewModel by Caliburn.

```
 public class GameBoardPageViewModel {
      public Game Game {
        get { return game; }
    }
 }
```

I see in the debugger that when AddMove is invoked, there is nobody listening to the PropertyChanged event (AddMove is invoked much more later than View and ViewModel constructing, so bindings are have to be established at that moment).

**Update 1.** 
If I call a notification of the Game property, then binding works. What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that the added Move's `ComposableWord` property's length is greater than 0?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. All is working properly. If I call notification on the Game property, then the binding works.

Comment: When is `game` assigned? Is it available at the time of binding? Since you do not notify it must available at that point otherwise it won't work

Comment: @dkozl, Oh, yes, indeed, thank you very much. It seems I'm tired))) You can post your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I call notification on the Game property, then the binding works

Since you do not raise `PropertyChanged` event for `Game` property it must be available at the time of binding otherwise binding mechanism won't be able to create link.